# Android P2P connection over Wifi

Tags: android, wifi, p2p

I am looking to implement a sort of Cloud distance app for friends such that when they are in close proximity to each other, some sort of alarm goes off.

From what I've gathered from googling, personal experience and reading related topics in SO,

direct Bluetooth = very small distance limitation

3g = Firewall problems

Centralized server/database = too "centralized" to fit criteria of a cloud app, and thus

I have been looking towards the android.net.wifi.p2p package to solve my needs.

A quick question to anyone who've used it before, does the connection only last when two devices are on the same LAN network?

Or does  "This lets an application discover available peers, setup connection to peers and query for the list of peers. When a p2p connection is formed over wifi, the device continues to maintain the uplink connection over mobile or any other available network for internet connectivity on the device. " include say some sort of wide area university network?

Thanks all for the time

Comment: A distance alarm that works on direct wifi will probably only work over ranges of 100m or so - probably less on phones, where power conservation is important. I suspect that you'll have to transmit GPS info across the internet instead. P2P would make for an interesting solution, but if you are passing location data of users who are not known to each other, you might run into some difficult privacy issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in the range of the device's WiFi capability, you can look into WiFi direct.
http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

It requires API level 14 or later.

Or, you can create a WiFi multicast network where you and your friends have the network configured with the same host address on each of your respective devices - but this requires a WiFi access point (router), although the router does not need to actually be connected to the internet.
[Multicast example.](https://code.google.com/p/frozenbubbleplus/source/browse/trunk/frozenbubbleplus/src/com/efortin/frozenbubble/MulticastManager.java)

Answer (score 0):

You could whip out your phones and both consentually open the unremovable Bloatware#Meta and drop location pins, gps has wide range vs wifi, 3,4,5g or Bluetooth. this type of functionality could go south really quick because its a nice idea if you'd like audible notification alerts when to inform you when the friend who put out a restraining order on you is within range. But other than that, .. if their your friends they will be there for you when you need them, but there's a right time and place for everything and this idea would surely get you to the right place at the right time for when they will be there for you.

Gps would be to extreme, borderline mobile stalkerapp. You could implement an airtag or any sort of gsm geolocation.  Oops "I found my friend before he found me, guess he had3g"

Everything aside, wouldn't this destroy the friendship by removing all coincidences and serendipity in friends bumping into each other?  I feel it would have more negative impact on friendships than any good it could implement. Opening doors to imbalance and controlling traits of ones subconscious